# Multi threading leading to race conditions

Tags: c#, multithreading, race-condition

Here is my snippet

```
Public async Task DoSomething(List<T> dataList)
{
    foreach (T claim in dataList)
    {
        var claimLineTask = AssembleClaimLines(claim);
        tasks.Add(claimLineTask);
    }
    await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    return dataList;
}

protected async Task AssembleClaimLines(T claim)
{
    connector.ConfigSettingsSection = "Claims.Lines";
    connector.QueryParameters = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        {“id”, claim.ID.ToString()},
    };
    claim.data = await connector.GetData()            
    return;
}
```

I have a race condition when calling `AssembleClaimLines()`.The values of the `connector.QueryParameters` are being overriden by one of the threads. Ultimately, I have lot of duplicate calls.

One easy fix is, I can pass `connector` as a parameter for `AssembleClaimLines`. But I cannot do that since `connector` is passed in from dependency injection. How else can I solve the race condition and still make full use of multi-threading ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either your `Connector` API needs to be changed to support multiple concurrent calls (e.g., moving `ConfigSettingsSection`/`QueryParameters` to arguments on `GetData`), or you'll need to get multiple `Connector` instances (e.g., inject a `ConnectorFactory` instead of a `Connector`).